# Check if Ping fails to connect and write to log

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script that connects to network drives and copies files using a list of IPs in a text document - the script is as below.

```
TITLE Upgrading Contactless Price Limit
ECHO starting  >> UpgradeLog.log
@ECHO on

rem CLS

echo Collect IP Address List
SET ListIP=C:\PMC\30To45Upgrade\tills.txt


echo Sets the folder we will use
SET PMC=C:\PMC\30To45Upgrade\VX820_cont45_Config\

ECHO Begin Mapping and Copying
ECHO.

echo Starts a FOR loop using the selected IP list

FOR /F %%a IN (%ListIP%) DO (

    echo This will attempt to log into the C$ share of the target PC.
    net use \\%%a\c$ /u:username password >NUL >> UpgradeLog.log

    ECHO.
    ECHO Copying directory to: %%a... >> UpgradeLog.log
    ECHO.

    echo Uses the Robocopy command to send the folder to the specified Till

    mkdir \\%%a\c$\retailjava\icc\VX820_cont45_Config
    C:\robocopy.exe %PMC% \\%%a\c$\retailjava\icc\VX820_cont45_Config /e /r:0 /w:10 /v /z >> UpgradeLog.log

    ECHO.
    ECHO Disconnecting from %%a... >> UpgradeLog.log
    ECHO.

    echo Disconnected from the share.
    net use \\%%a\c$ /DELETE>NUL >> UpgradeLog.log)
ECHO.  >> UpgradeLog.log
pause
```

However if the IP is offline it takes a long time to fail and move on to the next - I think the best solution if to ping the IP address first and if it does not respond move on to next

So a block of code like this

```
FOR /F %%a IN (%ListIP%) DO (
ping %%a >> Failed.log
)
```

However this block would write if it connected or not and I just want the failed pings - so not sure how to do this.

Also if I enter this in my code like this - even if it fails it carries on to the robocopy so it needs some sort of if/else statement as far as I can tell but not sure how to implement this. Any help?

**Attempted Fix**

```
TITLE Upgrading Contactless Price Limit
ECHO starting  >> UpgradeLog.log
@ECHO on

rem CLS

echo Collect IP Address List
SET ListIP=C:\PMC\30To45Upgrade\tills.txt


echo Sets the folder we will use
SET PMC=C:\PMC\30To45Upgrade\VX820_cont45_Config\

ECHO Begin Mapping and Copying
ECHO.

echo Starts a FOR loop using the selected IP list

FOR /F %%a IN (%ListIP%) DO (

ping %%a | find "TTL=" && (

    echo This will attempt to log into the C$ share of the target PC.
    net use \\%%a\c$ /u:username password >NUL >> UpgradeLog.log

    ECHO.
    ECHO Copying directory to: %%a... >> UpgradeLog.log
    ECHO.

    echo Uses the Robocopy command to send the folder to the specified Till

    mkdir \\%%a\c$\retailjava\icc\VX820_cont45_Config
    C:\robocopy.exe %PMC% \\%%a\c$\retailjava\icc\VX820_cont45_Config /e /r:2 /w:10 /v /z >> UpgradeLog.log

    ECHO.
    ECHO Disconnecting from %%a... >> UpgradeLog.log
    ECHO.

    echo Disconnected from the share.
    net use \\%%a\c$ /DELETE>NUL >> UpgradeLog.log

) || (
    echo %%a Failed to connect >> failed.log
)
)
ECHO.  >> UpgradeLog.log
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F %%a IN (%ListIP%) DO (
  ping %%a | find "TTL=" && (
    echo %%a is reachable
    rem insert your payload here
  ) || (
    echo %%a is not available
  )
)
```

where `&&` acts as "if previous command (`find`) was successful then" and `||` acts as "if previous command (`find`) failed then" (acts as "else" here)

Comment: This seems to work apart from the else it s logging the working IP and the failed IP - Added edited code above